# Communicate with 2 different tables (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm stuck on this dilemma here:

I have made a site, with a loginsytem in one table in a MySQL database. It contains personal information such as username, password, email.
The username is shown in every page as desired with `$_SESSION`s. Works perfectly.

When users are logged in, they can deliver answers to different sessions in another database.

I want the site to show users personal status of the session he/she has given.
The way im doing it now `echo` out status of all user sessions except the current user.

Can I, for example, put my `$_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";`
some how in a `<input value>`?

Comment: some how in a <input value=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question but you want to put your SESSION variable into an input field? In this case this input's name is myusername and the input field contains the username filled in as default value.

```
<?php
    echo '<input type="text" name="myusername" value="'.$_SESSION['mypassword'].'">';
?>
```

Comment: i think this is something that im looking for. but dont get the myusername value info the table from the form

Comment: do you know if i can use this $_sessions to the query to the table? like: $sql  = "SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE myusername = 'myusername'";

Comment: Got ut to work by; $sql="SELECT * FROM oppgave WHERE myusername ='{$_SESSION['myusername']}'";

Comment: Yes, as you've figured out, $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field="'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'";'; Why did you have '{' ? that's not needed.